# How to get objectify reference (Ref<T>) object to entity while executing a query on appengine datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

While upgrading Objectify in an Appengine Java-based application, I got stuck with a problem and here is a solution, I have tried to solve this but not sure how good it is?

The problem was
In the older version (Objectify 4.0b2), a query returned a Reference to the DB object.

```
Ref<EntityDO> refEntity = ofy().load().type(EntityDO.class).id(entityId);
```

This used to be a valid code as ofy().load().type().id() used to return a reference to the DB entity.

After upgrading Objectify to a later version, this has changed to

```
LoadResult<EntityDO> entityDO = ofy().load().type(EntityDO.class).id(entityId);
```

Now I used this code to convert the LoadResult<> object to Ref<> object.

```
  public static <T> Ref<T> getRef(LoadResult<T> loadResult) {
    if (loadResult != null) {
      T obj = loadResult.now();
      if (obj != null) {
        return Ref.create(obj);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

With this, I am able to get the Ref<> object successfully. My concern here is is this a good approach where to create a Ref<> object, we fetch the object from DB?

Thanks
Aadhaar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit peculiar. You could just call this, which is equivalent:

`Ref.create(Key.create(EntityDO.class, entityId))`

...but I'm guessing it's semantically not what you expect? I can't honestly remember exactly what 4.0b2 did (7 years ago), but at some point Objectify's `Ref` changed from being an object that held a direct object reference to an entity, to just being a holder of a `Key` with the ability to look up the value in the current session.

Without knowing more about your app it's hard to offer much advice. But if you just need a `Ref`, create it from a `Key`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.

I could use this approach everywhere where I had the id available.

For places where id is not available and we have a filter query, such as

ofy().load().type(EntityDO.class).filter("permission", "admin").first().

Is using "Ref.create(obj)" the possible way?

Comment: Sure, if you need a Ref, that's also a fine way to get one